# Node - Custom error helpers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, ecmascript-6

Trying to create custom helper methods to avoid repetitions, and i'm using `express-promise-router`

**app.js** created the error handler middle ware

```
//errorHandler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    //const error = app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
    const error = err;
    const code = err.code || '';
    const status = err.status || 500;

    res.status(status).json({
        isresponse: 1,
        res_time: Date(),
        res_id: 'tempororyid',
        res_data: {
            error: {
                code: code,
                message: error.message
            }
        }
    });

    console.log(err);
});
```

**errorHelper.js** for all the error helper methods

```
module.exports = {
    notFound: (req, res, next) => {
        const err = new Error('url not found please check the documentation');
            err.status = 404;
            err.code = 'URLNotFound';
            next(err);
    },

    emailExist: (req, res, next) => {
        const err = new Error('the email is already associated with another user account');
            err.code = 'EmailUsed';
            err.status = 400;
            next(err);
    }
};
```

**authController.js** for authentication

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const { emailExist } = require('../helpers/errorHelper');

module.exports = {
    signup: async (req, res, next) => {

        const userGuid = guid();
        const email = req.body.email;

        const existingUser = await User.findOne({email: email});

        if(existingUser) {
            emailExist();
        }

        const newUser = await User.create(req.body);

        res.status(200).json({
            isresponse: 1,
            res_time: Date(),
            res_id: 'TEMPID002',
            res_data: {
                success: 1,
                data: []
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Getting the following error

```
TypeError: next is not a function
    at emailExist (D:\Workspace\path\path\path\errorHelper.js:13:4)
    at signup (D:\Workspace\path\path\path\authController.js:26:4)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
POST /api/v1/signup 500 201.262 ms - 176
```

But if throwing error as below things works as expected

```
if(existingUser) {
    const error = new Error('the email is already associated with another user account');
        error.code = 'CR_NU_EmailUsed';
        error.status = 400;
        next(error);
}
```

looking for much needed help

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
module.exports = {
    notFound: () => {
        const err = new Error('url not found please check the documentation');
            err.status = 404;
            err.code = 'URLNotFound';
            return err;
    },

    emailExist: () => {
        const err = new Error('the email is already associated with another user account');
            err.code = 'EmailUsed';
            err.status = 400;
            return err;
    },
    
    response:(res ,res_data) => {
    
         res.status(200).json({
            isresponse: 1,
            res_time: Date(),
            res_id: 'TEMPID002',
            res_data
        });
        
    }
};
```

```js
const User = require('../models/User');
const { emailExist ,response} = require('../helpers/errorHelper');

module.exports = {
    signup: async (req, res, next) => {

        const userGuid = guid();
        const email = req.body.email;

        const existingUser = await User.findOne({email: email});

        if(existingUser) {
           return next(emailExist()); 
        }

        const newUser = await User.create(req.body);
        const res_data =  {
                success: 1,
                data: []
        }
        return response(res,res_data)
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you response i really appreciate it, your answer really helped me. can't thank you enough you are amazing.

Comment: i have quick question though, how do i prevent repeating the response i send for example `res.status(200).json({
   isresponse: 1,
   res_time: Date(),
   res_id: 'TEMPID002',
   res_data: {
    success: 1,
    data: newUser
   }
  });`

i just want to modify the `res_data` section

Comment: you mean making it global for the all app or just for the request?

Comment: yes for global, for every response from the server, `isresponse`, `res_time`, `res_id`, `res_data` remains same, the only thing changes is content of  `res_data` it may contain data or error, `res_data: {success: 1, data: []}` if error `res_data: {error:{code: '', message: ''} }`.

Comment: just like the global error handler, i'm trying to create something like global response handler, where i can pass `res_data` based on request. thank you

Comment: i edit my answer . i add a response function in the errors helper you can put it where ever you want but this is the concept

Comment: awesome thank you so much, i really appreciate you time.

Comment: glad to help (: